# Is it possible to narrow my REGEX search to the specific instance of the string I want?

Tags: python

I want to find the second instance of a string in a file. It's at the beginning of a line in the file and the previous line ends in a CRLF. Here's the string I get and the string I want in the order they appear in the file.

```
>  9 | 10 | Optimal    |    1 | HDD | B     | 1/9   0/10 <<== the str i get w/find
> 10 | 11 | Optimal    |    1 | HDD | A     | 0/11  1/12 <<<=== the string I want

To narrow the scope, I've tried including \n and \r and the hat-sign and none of them work to return the string I want. 

>>> pattern = re.compile(r' 10 \|')
>>> matches = pattern.finditer(searchstring)
>>> for match in matches:
    print(match)

> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(793, 798), match=' 10 |'> <<== the str i get w/find
> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(845, 850), match=' 10 |'> <<<=== the string I want
> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1488, 1493), match=' 10 |'>
> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1713, 1718), match=' 10 |'>
>>> 

## Another example of what I tried showing no matches found.
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(\n) 10 \|')
>>> for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

**## data format example**

```
>  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 0/10  |  3 | HD | 6 Gbps | HUC10 | S07 | Optimal    | RTEXKWKRR
>  1/4   |  4 | HD | 6 Gbps | HUC10 | S09 | Optimal    | L0TBLPVGK
>  1/9   |  5 | HD | 6 Gbps | HUC10 | S09 | Optimal    | HEDBPVTGK
>  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  0/10 |    14 | 06/12/16 00:04:57 | CHECK CONDITION
>  1/9  |    37 | 07/22/18 09:14:33 | CHECK CONDITION 


## Examples of what I've tried with the results

>>> with open((r'summary_a.out'), 'r')  as csvfile:
      searchstring = csvfile.read().strip()
      pattern = re.compile(r"^10\s+\|")
      matches = pattern.finditer(searchstring)
      for match in matches:
        print(match)

>>> No output.

## Other patterns tried with the same lack of output:
      pattern = re.compile(r"\\n10\s+\|")
      pattern = re.compile(r"\\n^10\s+\|")
      pattern = re.compile("\\n^10\s+\|")
      pattern = re.compile("^10\s+\|")
      pattern = re.compile('^10\s+\|')
      pattern = re.compile('/^10\s+\|')
**    pattern = re.compile('^1\/9\s+\|')

>>> No output.

** The following pattern, ('^1/9  |'), yielded results but not what was expected.
** Output         
> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
   -------------- lines deleted ---------------------
> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2525, 2525), match=''>
>>> 

## This pattern, ('^0/10  |'), yields the same results as above:
```

Comment: Is the data all nicely formatted like that? Can you tell us a bit about the format?

Comment: Thanks again @Alexander. I'll add it to my post.

Comment: Can you add that to your post? It's difficult to read as a comment.

Comment: All that data is in the same file?

Comment: Yes @Alexander; all that data is in the same file and sometimes strings I need to capture may be repeated, i.e. "1/9   |".

Comment: What is the rule for the first line being incorrect but the second one being correct? Is it that it is the second occurrence of `10`, or that it occurs after a line break, or both? It's hard to generalise from the one example you've given.

Comment: @kaya3 beat me to it. We need as much information as possible here.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @ kaya3. The rule is that "it occurs after a line break" and that the 10 being sought is a whole number and not part of a fraction. I am also looking for a fraction, "1/9", and it too occurs twice in the file. I want to construct a pattern that  identifies each.

Answer (score 0):

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/BE77Y0/1)

If you want to find the something at the start of the line you need to add a `^` at the start of your expression. So something like `r"^10\s+\|"` will work. Check the demo. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and the Demo link @adhilb. See my comments to Alexander Cecile, the search pattern you shared did not work. It worked in the Demo link but not for my file.

Comment: Actually @adhilb, when I put  a longer piece of the file in the Demo the pattern is missed! So there it goes, hmm. I am new to this so no telling what I'm missing so if someone can explain why the pattern is caught when only two lines are used but missed when more lines are added that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to isolate the second iteration of the format you will need to use this regex

```
import re

src = re.compile(r'(\n) 10 \|')
src.findall(searchstring)[1]
```

Using findall allows you to find all matching format cases in a string. "[1]" sets it to the second one.

Although if you have any further information or code please update.